# Could a holographic universe consist of 3D embedded in 4D instead of 3D embedded in 2D?

Tags: string-theory, spacetime-dimensions, holographic-principle

1. In the [holographic model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle), information about a given dimension can be embedded in a lower dimension, so our 3d universe could be considered as a 2d one. Could it happen the other way? I mean, could the information of a 3d universe be embedded in a 4d one? So we could actually say our 3d universe (not counting time as a dimension) was a 4d one?

Relevant links: [What if our universe was a hologram](https://futurism.com/what-if-our-universe-hologram/), [Could our universe be a hologram?](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2016/03/12/ask-ethan-could-our-universe-be-a-hologram/#1485a4772669)

Answer (score -2):

I see what your saying, a hologram is a 2d plane with a very detailed (but only partial view) of a 3d object. But you have to remember it is just on a 2d surface. Your saying that one step up, is our 3d universe a host to a 4d universe. While awesome to think, there is no current way of actually giving a definitive answer. The universe and its mysteries are amazing, and the theories we derive about it are even more amazing. Just as a 2d sprite cant see depth, we cant see in four dimensions, thats just how we were made.

check this link out: 
http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2009/03/30/why-cant-we-visualize-more-than-three-dimensions/